# Spooky haskell function that somehow knows your input

Tags: haskell

How can `sumListV3` function? `myFoldr` requires 3 args: function, base case num, and list. Yet it somehow knows the list (based on your input) even though it was never specified in the internal code.

I think `sumListV2` is the simplest it can go. How does `sumListV3` even compile, let alone function properly?

```
myFoldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
myFoldr _ baseCase [] = baseCase
myFoldr f b (x:xs) = f x (myFoldr f b xs)

sumListV2 :: [Int] -> Int
sumListV2 xs = myFoldr (+) 0 xs

sumListV3 :: [Int] -> Int
sumListV3 = myFoldr (+) 0
```

Comment: It's eta reduction.  Notice all sorts of wonderful uses, such as `plus = (+)` - how does it know there are two arguments? Eta reduction (googleable term).  `sumListV4 = sum` is more similar to your examples and the same concept.

Comment: Perhaps you don't buy that just because `foo xs = myFoldr (+) 0 xs` then we also know `foo = myFoldr (+) 0`. But do you buy the other implication? Does it make sense that if `foo = myFoldr (+) 0` then `foo xs = myFoldr (+) 0 xs`?

Answer (score 8):

Functions in Haskell are "curried".

This means that when you have a function `f :: a -> b -> c`, it's really `a -> (b -> c)`, and `f a b` is really `(f a) b` (because of associativity rules).

So when you run `f a b`, it first does `f a`, which returns a new function of type `b -> c`.  You can then give it a `b` and get your final answer of type `c`.

This lets you partially apply functions:

```
ghci> let add :: Int -> Int -> Int ; add a b = a + b
ghci> add 2 3
5
ghci> (add 2) 3
5
ghci> let addToTwo = add 2
ghci> :t addToTwo
addToTwo :: Int -> Int
ghci> addToTwo 6
8
ghci> addToTwo 9
11
```

What your example for `sumListV3` is doing is partially applying `myFoldr`. (Types here specified to your case.)

```
myFoldr       :: (Int -> Int -> Int) ->  Int ->  [Int] -> Int
myFoldr       :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> (Int -> ([Int] -> Int))
myFoldr (+)   ::                         Int -> ([Int] -> Int)
myFoldr (+) 0 ::                                 [Int] -> Int
sumListV3     ::                                 [Int] -> Int
```

Because `sumListV3` is defined as `myFoldr (+) 0`, you can replace `sumListV3` with `myFoldr (+) 0` in places where it is called:

```
sumListV3 [1,2] 
  = (myFoldr (+) 0) [1,2]
  = myFoldr (+) 0 [1,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Often there are multiple ways of defining a function in Haskell. In this case, you can use (basic) pattern matching on the argument `xs`

```
sumListV2 :: [Int] -> Int
sumListV2 xs = myFoldr (+) 0 xs
```

which, in this case, is very similar, conceptually, to the "usual" C-style syntax, in this case Javascript.

```
var sumListV2 =  function(xs) {
  return myFoldr(plusFunc, 0, xs)
}
```

Or you can define the function in terms of a composition of other functions, also known as pointfree style.

```
sumListV3 :: [Int] -> Int
sumListV3 = myFoldr (+) 0
```

In this case, the thing to note is that on the r.h.s. isn't the return value of `myFoldr`, but, because `myFoldr` has been partially applied* with two of its three arguments, it's a function that takes the remaining one, a list. So `sumListV3` is defined to be this: a function that takes a list.

An equivalent in Javascript is possible using `bind` to partially apply myFold.

```
var sumListV2 = myFold.bind(null, plusFunc, 0);
```

A really nifty thing about Haskell is that this is built into the language, so you don't need extra functions to do partial application. The tricky thing about Haskell, especially coming from other languages, is that you don't need extra functions to do partial application ;-). Tricky because the syntax for pattern matching and partial application is so similar while in other languages they are wildly different.

---

*It's not giving the entire picture, as it's more accurate to delve into currying and the fact that every function in Haskell just takes one argument, and a function that takes 3 is a "chain" of functions that return functions. But I find it a useful analogy, especially when comparing to partial application in other languages.